# Disable Internet Explorer across a set of PCs

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Is there a way to disable Internet Explorer on a number of PCs (Windows XP Pro and Windows 7) on an AD domain network? We have Firefox installed on those machines and don't want the users to run Internet Explorer.

Comment: Many applications use IE's rendering engine to show rich content in their client area (e.g. my applications, WoW's launcher, some anti-virus software). In other words: you want to remove the icon from their desktop, set Firefox as their default, and not allow them to use Start->Run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have AD setup, you can use Group Policy to set a Software Restriction for Iexplorer.exe.

- [How To use Software Restriction Policies in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324036)
- In a 2008/Win7 environment you can also use [AppLocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548340(WS.10).aspx).

Hope that helps...